# Stopping the Default Output in Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

Is there a way to Disable the default output shown in `Spark streaming`. Given below are the default output that is getting printed when running a spark streaming Application. I would like to see only the log messages(in the driver) that are added by me gets printed

```
spark-submit --class a11_TCP_IP.a11_Basic.a11_HelloTcp target/scala-2.10/sparkstreamingexamples_2.10-1.0.jar

16/04/27 13:20:15 WARN ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Restarting receiver with delay 2000 ms: Socket data stream had no more data
16/04/27 13:20:15 ERROR ReceiverTracker: Deregistered receiver for stream 0: Restarting receiver with delay 2000ms: Socket data stream had no more data
16/04/27 13:20:17 WARN ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Restarting receiver with delay 2000 ms: Socket data stream had no more data
16/04/27 13:20:17 ERROR ReceiverTracker: Deregistered receiver for stream 0: Restarting receiver with delay 2000ms: Socket data stream had no more data
-------------------------------------------
Time: 1461777618000 ms
-------------------------------------------

16/04/27 13:20:19 WARN ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Restarting receiver with delay 2000 ms: Socket data stream had no more data
16/04/27 13:20:19 ERROR ReceiverTracker: Deregistered receiver for stream 0: Restarting receiver with delay 2000ms: Socket data stream had no more data
-------------------------------------------
Time: 1461777621000 ms
-------------------------------------------

16/04/27 13:20:21 WARN ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Restarting receiver with delay 2000 ms: Socket data stream had no more data
```

Answer (score 3):

Your Spark folder should have a `conf/` directory. Inside that, there is a `log4j.properties` file. If not, copy `conf/log4j.properties.template` to `conf/log4j.properties`.

Now open `conf/log4j.properties` in an editor, and replace this line:

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, console
```

With these two:

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, null
log4j.appender.null=org.apache.log4j.varia.NullAppender
```

Comment: thanks. That does takes care of ERROR & WARN. But I am still getting this output `-------------------------------------------
Time: 1462045608000 ms
-------------------------------------------`

Comment: ok. I have finally identified. The output operation for `DStream`; `Dstream.print()` by default gives that output(ie `---- Time: .... `). I used another output operation `DStream.foreachRDD(..)` which helped to get rid of the issue

Answer (score 0):

I am using IntelliJ for Spark Streaming and not able to see conf folder. So using code to adjust the logging.

Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR) //Import needed libs